# DRF request.data issue with POST method

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm using DRF to test a api,when i POST a data,DRF return status_code 500 and error 'MacList' object has no attribute 'data'. but the GET is not problem.

Views:

```
class MacList(mixins.ListModelMixin,mixins.CreateModelMixin,generics.GenericAPIView):

queryset = Testable.objects.all()
serializer_class = TestableSerializer
def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    return self.list(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    return self.create(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
```

URLs:

```
path(r'api/maclist',views.MacList.as_view())
```

I'm checking the mixins.CreateModelMixin source code

```
class CreateModelMixin:

"""
Create a model instance.
"""
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data) **#### problem here**
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save()

def get_success_headers(self, data):
    try:
        return {'Location': str(data[api_settings.URL_FIELD_NAME])}
    except (TypeError, KeyError):
        return {}
```

if i use APIView to POST success.

```
class MacList(APIView):

def post(self,request):
    serializer = TestableSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Please help me!

Django-->3.0.8

djangorestframework-->3.11.0

Comment: please do format your code so that others can read

Comment: You don't need to pass ***`self`*** while calling the `list()` and `create()` method

Comment: Use `return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)` and `self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't need to pass derived class instance into inherited class method while calling it from derived class, when we use `self` python automatically pass this instance

It will works if you change your code to

```
.
.
def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```